# Why float becomes string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code in javascript:

```js
var childrenSize = 7;

    var flAmt = parseFloat(100);
    var amt   = parseFloat(flAmt/childrenSize);

    //Rounding-off fix
    var newAmt = (amt.toFixed(2))*childrenSize;
    alert(newAmt);
    var excess = 0;
    if(newAmt != flAmt)
        excess = parseFloat(flAmt - newAmt);
    amt = parseFloat(amt) + excess.toFixed(2);
    alert(amt);
```

`amt` should be 14.25. But instead, it becomes 14.285714285714286-0.03... why?
Also, how can I improve my code?

Comment: _"amt should be 100"_ Why? You divide 100 by 7.

Comment: What result are you expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/5zr7fz0z/

Comment: @j08691 it should be amt should be 14.25

Comment: @newbie Did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 2):

The [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function returns a string, so using the `+` operator performs a string concatenation instead of an addition.

To get the value of `14.26` which you were (almost) expecting, call `toFixed` after the addition, like so:

```
amt = (parseFloat(amt) + excess).toFixed(2);
```

However, `amt` is already a float, so is doesn't seem as though `parseFloat` is needed here.

Comment: Worth noting that you can convert it back to a number by placing a Unary Plus (`+`) symbol in front of it like so: `+(excess.toFixed(2))`.

Comment: see docs here: [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)